# Python - insert static class-method-value in class attribute dictionary

Tags: python, class, static-methods

How can I do this (without **init**):

```
class Test(Objekt, UserMixin): 
  
    @staticmethod
    def Foo():
        return 1

    my_dict = {
        "foo_val": Test.Foo(),
    }
```

I tried:

```
    my_dict = {
        "foo_val": lambda: Test.Foo(),
    }
```

But of course the lamda function is stored, not its result!

(this example is simplified)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few alternatives here:

call the function before decorating it with `staticmethod`:

```
class Test(Objekt, UserMixin): 
  
    def Foo():
        return 1

    my_dict = {
        "foo_val": Foo(),
    }

    Foo = staticmethod(Foo)
```

Or, add it to the dictionary outside the class statement:

```
class Test(Objekt, UserMixin): 

    my_dict = {}

    @staticmethod
    def Foo():
        return 1

Test.my_dict["foo_val"] = Test.Foo()
```

Finally, use the `__func__` attribute of the `staticmethod` object:

```
class Test(Objekt, UserMixin): 
  
    @staticmethod
    def Foo():
        return 1

    my_dict = {
        "foo_val": Foo.__func__(),
    }
```

Not sure which of these three approaches is the cleanest, to be frank.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `my_dict` as `property`

```
@property
def my_dict(self):
    return {"foo_val": Test.Foo()}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to declare `my_dict` as a class property (or a normal instance property, if that's okay for your use case, that would save you from using the `classproperty` class).

```
class classproperty(property):
    def __get__(self, cls, owner):
        return self.fget.__get__(owner)()

class Test():

    @staticmethod
    def Foo():
        return 1

    @classproperty
    def my_dict(cls):
        return {
            "foo_val": cls.Foo(),
        }

print(Test.my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'foo_val': 1}
```

Using a normal property:

```
class Test():

    @staticmethod
    def Foo():
        return 1

    @property
    def my_dict(cls):
        return {
            "foo_val": cls.Foo(),
        }

print(Test().my_dict) # notice that this requires to create an instance!
```

Another way could be to

1. use a metaclass
2. fill `my_dict` after the class definition

Comment: What's the point of using `classmethod` here? why not just: `return self.fget.__get__(owner)()`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga good point, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all!
Just for completion. Another solution could be:

```
class Test(Objekt, UserMixin): 
  
    @staticmethod
    def Foo():
        return Test.my_dict["foo_val"]

    my_dict = {
        "foo_val": 1,
    }
```

As mentioned, this is a special case and the "foo_val" entry has to be item of that dict! Thus I think this is a valid solution here. Otherwise I wold  prefer one og the other solutions mentioned in this thread